# SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement while saving the data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement while saving the data

I am getting SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement while saving the data.

If I am executing the same in data view not getting any error.

My  Model :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "area")
@TypeDef(
        name = "json",
        typeClass = JsonType.class
)
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "subject", columnDefinition = "json")
    @Type(type = "json")
    private List<Map<String, String>> relation;

    @Column(name = "roll")
    private String roll;

    @Column(name = "class")
    private String class;

   
}
```

In Service Impl :

```
myRepo.saveStudent(id, name, roll, class);
```

All the variable value are avilabel

My Repo :

```
 @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into student (id, name, roll, class) values (:id, :name, :roll, :class", nativeQuery = true)
    void saveStudent(String id, String name, String roll, String class);
```

Can anybody help me what sql grammer is wrong here,

Comment: You are missing the closing ')' after your values

Comment: @johnnyutts thanks it worked. if you want to answer then please do or else  will delete because its syntax issue. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing ')' after your values